# Sum of 2 uncorrelated numbers

Tags: statistics

Can we always RMS, two uncorrelated error to get their total contribution/error to the system? what is the idea/math behind it.

Answer (score 0):

The math behind it is that if $X,Y$ are independent and normally distributed with means $\mu_X,\mu_Y$ and standard deviations $\sigma_X,\sigma_Y$, then $Z=X+Y$ is also normally distributed with mean $$
  \mu_Z = \mu_X + \mu_Y,
$$
and standard deviation $$
  \sigma_Z = \sqrt{\sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2}.
$$

The latter is often written as $$
  \sigma_Z^2 = \sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2
$$
instead, and shows that for sums of normally distributed variables, you can simply sum the individual means and *variances* to get the mean and *variance* of the sum. (The *variance* is simply the square of the standard deviation)

Comment: Normality seems irrelevant.